# Django select the account from the account tree displays all the account details

Tags: javascript, json, django, checkbox

**I want when I select the account from the account tree using the checkbox it displays all the account details on the other side so I can add or edit an account later. What makes it difficult for me is that it relies on a tree system**

---

### **Please Help**

[image]

html

```
{%load static%} 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Daleel</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'image/daleel.ico'%}" >
    <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'%}">
    <!-- Bootstrap 5 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"  integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.14/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/acc.css'%}">
</head>
<body>
    <h3 class="title">Accounts Tree</h3>
    <hr>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class='up'>
            <div class='acc'>
                <br>
                <div class="d-flex" role="search">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Search</button>
                </div>
                <br>
                {% for mainacc in mainaccs %}
                <ul class="tree" id="tree">
                    <li>
                        <details >
                            <summary class="mainacc" > <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="acc1"  id="{{ aacc.acc_id1 }}" value="{{ mainacc.acc_id1 }}" style="margin-top:10px">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ mainacc.acc_id1 }} ====>> {{ mainacc.E_name1 }}</summary>
                            <ul>
                                {% for aacc in mainacc.aacc_set.all %}
                                <li>
                                    <details>
                                        <summary class="aacc"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="acc2" id="{{ aacc.acc_id2 }}" value="{{ aacc.acc_id2 }}" style="margin-top:10px">&nbsp;&nbsp; {{ aacc.acc_id2 }} ====>> {{ aacc.E_name2 }}</summary>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                {% for bacc in aacc.bacc_set.all %} 
                                                <details>
                                                    <summary class="bacc"><input class="form-check-input"  type="radio" name="acc3" id="{{ aacc.acc_id3 }}"  value="{{ bacc.acc_id3 }}" style="margin-top:10px">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ bacc.acc_id3 }} ====>> {{ bacc.E_name3 }}</summary>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        {% for cacc in bacc.cacc_set.all %}
                                                        <li>    
                                                            <summary class="cacc"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="acc4" id="{{ aacc.acc_id4 }}" value="{{ cacc.acc_id4 }}" style="margin-top:10px">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ cacc.acc_id4 }} ====>> {{ cacc.E_name4 }}</summary>
                                                        </li>
                                                        {% endfor %}
                                                    </ul>
                                                </details>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </details>
                                </li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        </details>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="br">
            </div>
            <div class= 'card' id="account-details"> 
                <br>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3" id="example">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="id" style="width:140px;font-size:16px;font-weight:450">Account No.</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" name="acc_id" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="E_name" style="width:140px;font-size:16px;font-weight:450">English Name</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" name="E_name4" >
                </div>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="A_name" style="width:140px;font-size:16px;font-weight:450">Arbic Name</span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" name="A_name4">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="MAC" style="width:140px;font-size:16px;font-weight:450">Main Account</span>
                    <select class="form-select"  id='select'>       
                        <option value=""> </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="Nature" style="width:140px;font-size:16px;font-weight:450">Nature of account</span>
                    <select class="form-select"  id='select2'>      
                        <option value=""> </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="Type" style="width:140px;font-size:16px;font-weight:450">Type of account</span>
                    <select class="form-select"  id='select2'>  
                        <option value=""> </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" autocomplete="off">
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1"><i class='fas fa-plus'></i> Add</label>
                
                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2" autocomplete="off">
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="btnradio2"><i class='fas fa-pen'></i> Edit</label>
                
                    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio3" autocomplete="off">
                    <label class="btn btn-outline-danger" for="btnradio3"><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i> Delete</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </form> 
        <!-- jquery 5-->
    <script src="{% static  'js/code.jquery.com_jquery-3.7.0.js'%}"></script>
    <script src="{% static  'js/cdn.jsdelivr.net_npm_gijgo@1.9.14_js_gijgo.min.js'%}"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap 5--> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gijgo/1.9.14/combined/js/gijgo.min.js" integrity="sha512-JsHMa3rSDTAy7MZCj1DWbL0YwAAysj23aWwCOTWKs3tlqO3ptwDhw3OHimYoeqryhTmSLFRn29C8qHK/oT/iZA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="{% static  'js/cdn.jsdelivr.net_npm_bootstrap@5.0.2_dist_js_bootstrap.bundle.min.js'%}"></script>
    <script>
        var radios = $('[class="form-check-input"]');
        radios.change(function() {
            radios.not(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
    </script>
    <script> // make button save work1 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnradio2").click(function () {
            $("#edit-form").submit();
        });
    });
</script> 

<script>// make button save work2
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // ... your existing JavaScript code ...
    
        $('#btnradio2').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission behavior
    
            // Collect form data
            const formData = $('#edit-form').serialize();
    
            // Send a POST request to your server
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'add_entry', // Update with your correct URL
                data: formData,
                success: function (response) {
                    // Handle the success response, e.g., show a success message
                    alert('Entry saved successfully!');
                    // You can also redirect the user to another page if needed
                    // window.location.href = '/success-page/';
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    // Handle errors, e.g., show an error message
                    alert('Error: Unable to save entry.');
                }
            });
        });
    });
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

models.py

from django.db import models

```
# Create your models here.

Nature = (
    ('Balance Sheet', 'BalanceSheet'),
    ('Income Statement', 'Income Statement')
)
Type = (
    ('Debit', 'Debit'),
    ('Credit', 'Credit')
)
class Mainacc (models.Model):
    acc_id1 = models.IntegerField(unique=True,db_index=True)
    E_name1 = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    A_name1 = models.CharField(max_length=12 , null=True,blank=True)
    nature1 = models.CharField( max_length=20,choices=Nature,default='Balance Sheet')
    type1 = models.CharField( max_length=20,choices=Type,default= 'Debit')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f' {self.acc_id1} <==> {self.E_name1}'

class Aacc (models.Model):
    acc_id1 = models.ForeignKey(Mainacc, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    acc_id2 = models.IntegerField(unique=True,db_index=True)
    E_name2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    A_name2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True,blank=True)
    nature2 = models.CharField( max_length=20,choices=Nature,default='Balance Sheet')
    type2 = models.CharField( max_length=20,choices=Type,default= 'Debit')
    def __str__(self):
        return f' {self.acc_id2} <==> {self.E_name2}'

    
class Bacc (models.Model):
    acc_id2 = models.ForeignKey(Aacc, on_delete =models.CASCADE)
    acc_id3 = models.IntegerField(unique=True,db_index=True)
    E_name3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    A_name3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True,blank=True)
    nature3 = models.CharField( max_length=20,choices=Nature,default='Balance Sheet')
    type3 = models.CharField( max_length=20,choices=Type,default= 'Debit')
    def __str__(self):
        return f' {self.acc_id3} <==> {self.E_name3}'
    
class Cacc (models.Model):
    acc_id3 = models.ForeignKey(Bacc, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    acc_id4 = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True,db_index=True)
    E_name4 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    A_name4 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True,blank=True)
    nature4 = models.CharField( max_length=20,choices=Nature,default='Balance Sheet')
    type4 = models.CharField( max_length=20,choices=Type,default= 'Debit')
    def __str__(self):
        return f' {self.acc_id4} <==> {self.E_name4}'
```

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from . models import Mainacc
from . models import Aacc
from . models import Bacc
from . models import Cacc
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse



def Accounts(request):
    mainacc_list = Mainacc.objects.all()
    context = {'mainaccs': mainacc_list}
    return render(request, 'templates\\acc\\acc.html', context)

def Json(request):
    data = (serializers.serialize('json', Mainacc.objects.all()),
            serializers.serialize('json', Aacc.objects.all()),
            serializers.serialize('json', Bacc.objects.all()),
            serializers.serialize('json', Cacc.objects.all()),
            )
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts', views.Accounts, name='accounts'),
    path('json', views.Json, name='Json'),
]
```

**Please Help**